# Filters for Veiling/Smearing and ghost detections of SICK LiDAR data

Tags: pointcloud, lidar, sick

I'm having trouble with LiDAR data from a SICK MRS1104C (4-layer 360°) on data that was collected in an orchard. Specifically, I observe ghost detections when I measure non-dense vegetation as can be seen here [image: image of the observed "second crop row"] where a false second crop detection appears in roughly twice the distance of the actual crop row.

I believe this is a common effect that has been described before ([see this conference paper](https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub4/tuley_john_2004_1/tuley_john_2004_1.pdf)) but so far I was not able to come up with a good solution regarding filtering of these points without losing range on the sensor. Has anyone had success with a certain filtering algorithm or can point me to a good publication regarding this? Or are there any settings of lidar or the sick_scan_xd driver I can use to alleviate this?